# Fotos do DevDay 2015

Tags: debate

Pra quem não viu, publiquei as fotos no nosso grupo no Facebook:

https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=oa.791280331017975&type=1

Comment: Podias identificar ;)

Comment: Deu preguiça. Depois eu faço.

Comment: @JorgeB. [Nessa foto](https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpt1/v/t1.0-9/12208760_10207105267885264_2075783636544385546_n.jpg?oh=e6575acbb154a0bdab734c059838f2b4&oe=56C09352&__gda__=1454770779_516b531160717e547170755ed498b2dc) tem o Gabe, JulioBorges, mgibsonbr, Cigano, Eu, Amigo do Gabe que esqueci o nome e a Roberta

Comment: @JorgeB. você veio pro Brasil?

Comment: Legal ter conhecido a galera que esteve no evento.

Comment: O que tinha nessas caixas que o Gabe e a Roberta têm na mão? ;)

Comment: Por que os crachás tem o ícone de salvar do word? :D